# ¿Qué significa "como agua para chocolate"?

Tags: expresiones, diferencias-regionales, méxico

I know that "como agua para chocolate" means "like water for chocolate". And I am aware that it is a [novel](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Como_agua_para_chocolate_(novela)) (and there is film made after the novel), which has its origin in Mexico.

But, I heard it said in a [song](http://www.dicelacancion.com/letra-alerta-roja-daddy-yankee) now.

> Y esto está como agua para chocolate

Now, the group that sang that part is "Gente de Zona", which is a Cuban reggaeton group.

This leaves me with two questions, my main question is "what does it mean?" Not in the sense of, translate it to English, as I know the translation. But what is meant by saying it. And my second question would be, how well known is that saying outside of Mexico? I am aware that the novel became popular in more Spanish-speaking countries, so it doesn't surprise me that people from Cuba know this.

Comment: Este dicho es el equivalente de "no esta el horno para bollos" en Espana.

Comment: @aparente [tag:modismos] y [tag:expresiones] no son lo mismo pero podrían serlo, por lo que antes de ir reetiquetando sería bueno ofrecer respuestas en [¿Cómo podríamos clasificar las etiquetas por tipos de sentencias?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2926/1674)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Succinctly explained in [Como agua para chocolate: Un dicho mexicano hecho novela](http://www.speakinglatino.com/como-agua-para-chocolate/):

> "Como agua para chocolate" es un popular dicho mexicano que significa
>   estar molesto o muy furioso. El mismo compara el estado en el cual
>   tiene que estar el agua -hirviendo- para preparar chocolate.

That is, it is a saying to state that someone is extremely furious. It uses the link with the water, that needs to be very warm to be useful for chocolate.

Reading the question [Qué significa la expresion "como agua para chocolate"?](https://es.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070330085044AAnfl6R) I also get some other meanings:

- to be so angry
- to be "warm" in a luxurious way. That is, to be in a sexual appealing mood.

And also this one that is quite well explained:

> Es una expresión y un modismo. Cuando preparas agua para hacer
>   chocolate caliente, debe estar en su punto, de lo contrario el
>   chocolate no hará espuma, osea, debe estar a la perfección y listo. De
>   manera que si estas "como agua para chocolate", implica que estas
>   listo para lo que viene, sea bueno o malo. Tambien suele utilizarse
>   para decir que estas tan enojado que arremeterás en contra de quien
>   sea.

I haven't read the novel myself, but from what I see it may have a double use as per someone who is very impulsive in relationships, both in love and hate.

---

Regarding its usage throughout Spanish speaking countries, in Spain we do not use it.

Comment: I would say it's only used in Mexico, not aware that people in any other country used. Good question. The novel it's a great one, worth to read it!

Comment: @DelonixR. would you say the novel could be understood by someone without a good understanding of Spanish. I have been learning Spanish for about 10 months now, but I use it almost daily. (Mexican in-laws, hence I knew about the novel)?

Comment: Hi @DylanMeeus, I would say give it a try. If you enjoy the reading, keep going. If not, you always can close the book at any moment you want (That is one of any reader's right.. , another one that I just remember is that you can skip pages ;) . Just in case, the author is Laura Esquivel.

Comment: I was about to offer some suggestions, but apparently the answer is locked, so no joy here. I suggest: 1. **luxury**/*lujo*is a well known false friend of **lust**/*lujuria* also feeling “warm” is awkward in that context, should be “hot”. 2. Regarding the meaning "just the right conditions" from yahoo answers is doubtful at least. I’d remove the quote (takes half the article on mobile) and mention the probable meaning as doubtful 'till a reference can either confirm or deny it.

Comment: @hlecuanda oh, so strange it shows as locked to you. Just try it out again. If the problem persists I can make it community wiki so it is easier to edit and I do not get attribution from your improvings :)

Comment: Maybe it's because I have a pending draft on it... Let's head over to meta and solve it. Attribution is fine as it is, rep is good,  but good nswers will be here long after we're gone.

Comment: @hlecuanda thanks. Otherwise, you can just post another answer. Since you are the one who knows the subject better (you are the one speaking Spanish from Mexico), you may have enough to make a correct, useful answer.

Comment: @hlecuanda Oh, now I understand the problem. It is a bug and Diego reported it in Meta: [Content of previous post is there when I click “ask (new) question”](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2606/1674)

Comment: @hlecuanda - Did you want to come back to this and do some editing?